# Can a closed simple 2D curve be a less-than-1-dimensional fractal?

Tags: general-topology, fractals

**The question:** Can a **closed simple 2D curve** (by *2D curve*, I mean a 1-dimensional continuum on a 2-dimensional plane) be a **less-than-1-dimensional fractal** (by *dimension*, I mean Hausdorff dimension) ?

I've searched through some famous fractals, none of them satisfy. Maybe there is a theorem that prevents the answers, but I'm too new to topology to notice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. The topological dimension is one by assumption and the Hausdorff dimension always exceeds the topological dimension. This is proved for compact sets as theorem 6.3.11 in [Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387747484) and more generally in section 3.1 of [Integral, Probability, and Fractal Measures](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387982052)

Comment: @MarkMcClure: By "exceeds" you mean $\ge$, of course. Just for the record, the theorem itself is due to L. Sznirelman.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Correct.